# Redirect after login to the original url in react-router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

Hi I am using erikras' [react-redux-universal-hot-example](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example)

My problem is that I am trying to visit a page lets say "/chat" and in doing so I should be redirected to the "/login" page since it needs authentication. Once I complete authentication I should be redirected back to the original url which is "/chat".

I was trying to use onEnter hook but that didn't work. Currently the after login we are redirecting users to "/loginSuccess" page by default (hard coded)

thanks in advance for all the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would approach this from a high level...

1. When you redirect to `/login`, add the current route to the next route's location state.
2. Handle login.
3. When navigating to `/loginSuccess`, check for the location state for the route you initially passed, and redirect to that.

It could look like this...

```
// function passed to the onEnter to handle authentication check
redirectIfNotLoggedIn(nextState, replace) {
  if (notLoggedIn) {
    replace({
      pathname: '/login',
      state: {
        redirectTo: nextState.location.pathname
      }
    })
  }
}

// function passed to the onenter to handle loginSucesss redirect
redirectAfterLoggedIn(nextState, replace) {
  if(nextState.location.state.redirectTo) {
    replace(nextState.location.state.redirectTo) // you might need to prepend '/'
  }
}
```